# docker dnsmasq wildcard sub domains not supported?

Tags: docker, wildcard, dnsmasq

I want *.virtualtest.com any subdomain + virtualtest.com main domain to point back to docker localhost for testing in my nginx+php docker
Ping anyrandomgenerated.virtualtest.com 127.0.0.1 should be
I do not want manually to add every single sub domain via --add-host
--add-host /etc/hosts is NOT enough for me, I really need wildcard*.domain.ltd support
why can't I use dnsmasq wildcards in docker?
So simple yet so difficult…
Also why Docker removes my edit nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf settings all the time????
address=/virtualtest.com/127.0.0.1

I get this error in Docker container
docker exec -it 437925a20935 sh -c 'service dnsmasq restart'
 * Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq
dnsmasq: setting capabilities failed: Operation not permitted

Please help I am going insane over here!

Comment: Put your Dockerfile. Put your docker run command.

Comment: Just for troubleshooting, add `--cap-add ALL` to your `docker run` command. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities